# Как ограничить количество отправляемых форм с сайта?

Tags: wordpress

Имеется сайт на WP, на котором реализована отправка форм через PHP Mailer.

Проблема в том, что если многократно нажимать на кнопку отправить, то отправляется соответствующее количество форм.

Как можно ограничить количество форм, либо установить тайм-аут?

Подскажите пожалуйста, это мой первый проект на реальном хостинге и сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Comment: Вы можете при отправке формы скрывать элементы формы и показывать что-то вроде "Ваше сообщение отправлено"

Comment: Используй плагины форм. Это позволит решить не только это проблему, но и кучу других, о которых ты ещё не подозреваешь.